# Fitting a new outside floodlight

Tags: wiring

I am trying to fit a new outside floodlight. I bought one online as you do these days hoping the wiring would be the same as my previous one.

The new one has, in addition to the standard 240V mains ac cables, a separate black and white cable.

I am attaching pictures.

I can only assume that the black/white cable is to fit a motion sensor to it. In the leaflet within the box there is no mention of this additional cable.

I am not wanting to attach a motion sensor to this, but merely to use it through a conventional switch.

Can anyone help with explaining what these cables are and if I can still connect and use this floodlight ?

thanks

Panos[image]

Comment: Hmm. Came from Amazon or Alibaba straight from China? No documentation, perhaps also no actual approval from the relevant authority on acceptable electrical equipment in your country? Send it back. Some of that stuff is quite dangerous.

Comment: Send it back and give it a bad review!   Never mind (what you assume is) the extra pair of wires.  How do you know that (what you assume is) the power cable is for 240V?   Maybe it wants 12V?  That'll be fun if you hook it up to mains.  You'll get light, heat, and entertainment.  :). Send it back.

Comment: Did it really come with no literature? Have you looked for documentation online? It's unlikely that any of us knows this specific model intimately enough to answer.

Comment: To be fair though, some cheap products have their documentation in the sale listing on line or they include a small card with a URL for the docs.  Did you look?  I'm ok with companies that do it that way.

Comment: The black and white could be for dimming the blue brown green is normally the power blue neutral brown and green earth. I would want documentation before hooking anything up. A model number number may be helpful but I would be leaving a bad review for no connection data.

Comment: @jay613 except the building and electrical codes call out approved products, i.e. products that have cleared a system of quality assurance, such as UL, BSI, TUV, CSA, etc. Those "cheap products" do an end-run around that apparatus, overwhelming Customs with sheer volume, to slip utterly defective products into your lap.  For instance the plastic is cheap, and not the special type borated to be fire retardant, so instead of containing an arc-fed fire, it melts and catches fire *itself* and now shutting off the power will not stop the fire! Dangerous stuff.   Of course ignorance is bliss lol.

Comment: Since all those quality standards require documentation in the box, *the lack thereof* is a sure sign of cheap junk that is illegal to install.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I mostly agree with you.  I lower my standard substantially for things where the safety risks are contained, like battery-powered driveway lights, a headlight for my snow thrower, and so on.   For something like this light, I completely agree.  And to your point, those cable grommets don't look especially outdoorsy.  I really should take another look at my cheap cake mixer. :(